# mosquitto.conf: bridged topic names with spaces

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I need to bridge given topis from one mosquitto to another. The problem is there are spaces in the topics:

```
/sensors/DS 1
/sensors/DS 2
/sensors/..
/sensors/DS 32
```

I am looking for a solution how to configure only a few topics that I need:

```
# /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/bridge.conf
# ...

# This works fine but produces unwanted traffic:
topic /sensors/# out 1

# This all doen't work:
topic /sensors/DS\ 4 out 1
topic '/sensors/DS 4' out 1
topic "/sensors/DS 4" out 1
```

Anyway I am catching the `Error: Invalid bridge topic direction '4'.`

Is it possible to solve this issue?

`mosquitto version 1.4.15 (build date Thu, 07 Jun 2018 19:59:46 +0300)`

[MOSQUITTO.CONF(5)](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html)

**UPD** Bug report created: https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1756

Comment: This looks like a bug, I've looked at the code and it looks to be just splitting on spaces. Please raise a bug on [github](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues)

Comment: Thank you, @hardillb. Can you please give proof link to this peace of code? if it doesn't bother you. I'l add into the bugreport. (I'm not very good in c and mosquitto codebase.)

Comment: Spaces in Topic strings are not considered to be a 'Best Practice ....just for this reason. https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices/

Comment: Despite the Best Practice afaik Spaces in Topic is the Common Practice (at least not rare). Because HW vendors force to make a choice in favor of cheap IoT devices with saving on Best Practices, too.